# How to setup time alarm as a silent vibration?

Tags: mobile-applications, ios, smart-watches

I've bought a smart bracelet ([ID115 by LETSCOM](https://www.letscom.com/products/fitness-tracker-id115-black/)) for its silent alarms as advertised:

> Wake you up peacefully with **a silent alarm**.
>
> Alarm Alert: Set silent alarms on the tracker to wake you up **without disturbing your family**.

However, when setup *Alarm Alert* as *Get Up* in *VeryFitPro* app (for iOS) and synced via Bluetooth, but the bracelet keeps beeping till I start shaking my hand or by pressing the button, therefore it's disturbing others. What I'm looking for is to set up the alarm using silent vibration only (without beeping).

[image: Alarm Alert, Get Up, VeryFitPro app, iOS)]

I've checked the app and [manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zHflD2wEScjevBiZDui3757XgM3_8I2O/view?usp=sharing), but it's not clear for me how to do it.

Comment: the website implies that the device wakes you with a silent alarm once it learns your routine

Answer (score 2):

I've found that this can be achieved using *Sedentary Alert* in *VeryFitPro* app for iOS, by selecting the start and finish time with the interval, and a smart watch will only vibrate in the morning when not active.

[image: Sedentary Alert in VeryFitPro app for iOS]